# Fraud detection with machine learning with partialy labeled data

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series, anomaly-detection, one-class-classification

I am facing difficulties handling an issue with my dataset. The purpose of my analysis is to find an electricity thief given a dataset.

**The first dataset:** contains the list of all customers (unlabeled, because we don’t know who might be committing fraud). Besides some features, we have a determined amount of months of consummation (same length).
The second dataset: consists of previously caught thieves. (Note: a fraudster can be caught many times) .

| ID | F1 | F2 | January2020 | February2020 | …. | December2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 52 | … | 45 | 85 | ... | 35 |
| 2 | 78 | … | 85 | 75 | ... | 39 |
| … | … | … | …. | …. | …. | …. |
| 484419 | 74 | … | 82 | 74 | …… | 87 |

| ID | month | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | january | 2020 |
| 2 | February | 2021 |
| 1 | August | 2021 |
| … | … | … |
| 464 | apri2021 |  |

**Problem:** At the first hand I thought that the problem can be handled as a time series or sequence classification or anomaly classification. But then I realized that the dataset is unlabeled with only few people labeled as Fraudsters.

Could anyone give me a suggestion about how to handle this issue and if possible some references where I can find some examples?